# Floating Action Button doesn't work on other phones

Tags: java, android, api, floating-action-button

i have builded an app that use a floating action button. On my app, that i use to thest the apps, the FAB work fine. On my phone i have Android 5.0.1. I have sended an APK of my app to two friedns, one have Android 4.2.2 and the other 4.1.2. On this phones the FAB doesn't work. When you click on it nothing happens.

This is the manifest of my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tutecentral.mygames">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".OptionActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <!--
         ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
         App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".GameFocusActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Is it possible that FAB isn't compatible with andorid with API before 19?

### UPDATE

Here is the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tutecentral.mygames"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/nearby_fregment_card_user_showme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:fabSize="normal" /

FloatingActionButton showMe;
showMe = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.nearby_fregment_card_user_showme);
showMe.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v == showMe)
        {
            // event code
        }
   }
```

Check my code. I user it this way and in my app working fine in all version

Comment: I had setted min sdk 15. I test  yet.